How to get rid of multiple "Windows Boot Managers"?
Before, Windows was present on my drive, before I accidentally deleted it.
Now, I did reinstall Windows, however, there were two boot options.
Even when deleting the improper option from my BIOS, it keeps regenerating and coming back for my soul.
How do I fix this?
NOTE (12/18/2024):
Apparently, Windows recognises the boot option (once it regenerates) as a Firmware Application.
Here's the full output.
https://pastebin.com/iQNpTVPe

Do both options work equally? Do they both show up in bcdedit /enum firmware from within Windows? Does efibootmgr from within some Linux show both of them?

Depends.
If I remove the boot option and reboot. no Boot option appears in either.
BUT, after another reboot, the broken boot manager comes back and appears in both.
However, in Windows (i just found this. I'll add it to the post), Windows takes it as a Firmware Application (101fffff).
Here's the output.
https://pastebin.com/iQNpTVPe
